# Select column containing several value with range of number in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe `

```
A            Variant&Price                Qty
AAC           7:124|25: 443                1
AAD             35:|35:                    1
AAS           32:98|3:40                   1
AAG             2: |25:                    1
AAC          25:443|26:344                 1
```

and I want to get variant which has one of its values is below 7

```
A            Variant&Price                 Qty
AAC           7:124|25: 443                1
AAS            32:9|3:40                   1
AAG             2: |25:                    1
```

Note that first digit is the variant, as well as the third digit (variant always before `:`)
I can apply this code,

```
split_df = df['Variant&Price'].str.split(':|\|', expand=True)
print(df[split_df.iloc[:, [0,2]].astype(int).min(axis=1) <= 7])
```

But what if I want to get, instead of 7, it is now range from 2 to 7. I ve tried `>=2 & <=7` but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) the number before `:`, convert to integer and check if [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) is [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) 2 and 7:

```
m = (df['Variant&Price'].str.extractall('(\d+):')[0]
     .astype(int).between(2,7).groupby(level=0).any()
    )

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
     A  Variant&Price  Qty
0  AAC  7:124|25: 443    1
2  AAS     32:98|3:40    1
3  AAG        2: |25:    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cond1 = (df['Variant&Price'].str.split('|').explode()
         .str.split(':').str[0]
         .astype('int')
         .between(2, 7).max(level=0))

df[cond1]
```

output:

```
    Am  Variant&Price   Qty
0   AAC 7:124|25: 443   1
2   AAS 32:98|3:40      1
3   AAG 2: |25:         1
```

Comment: It has a `FutureWarning` though